# Why cout doesn't work?

Tags: c++, loops, io, iostream, cin

When I try to read input from console like this :

```
6 6 4
1 1 1
2 1 1
1 2 1
2 2 1
```

With following code piece, for each line of triplets, I simple want to compute (n/a+1)*(m/a+1) and output the result to console.

```
while(cin.get()!='\n'){
    int n=0, m = 0, a =0;
    cin >> n >> m >> a;

    cout <<(n/a+1) * (m/a+1) << endl;

}
```

However, it doesn't work, why?

Comment: You do know that `cin.get()` will *extract* a character from the input buffer. That character will be lost forever. If you want to read one line at a time, then use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for the extraction.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. "it doesn't work" Can you tell what happens ?

Comment: shin I answered your question, did you see it?

Comment: FYI `(n/a+1) * (m/a+1)` will overflow if **n** and **m** are 100,000 and **a** is single digit number. Type cast the multiplication result to `long int` sice **m**,**n**,**a** are integers. Like this `(long int)((n/a+1) * (m/a+1))`

Answer (score 7):

Here:

```
while(cin.get()!='\n')
```

you extract a character from standard input, every time the loop's condition evaluates.

As a result, that character is already consumed when you try to parse your triplet.

---

Use [std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) to parse the input line by line, and from each line, get the triplet.

Example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int n, m, a;
        if (!(iss >> n >> m >> a)) { break; } // error
        std::cout <<(n/a+1) * (m/a+1) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
4
6
6
9
```

---

PS: FYI `(n/a+1) * (m/a+1)` will *overflow* if `n` and `m` are 100,000 and `a` is single digit number. Type cast the multiplication result to `long int` sice `m`,`n`,`a` are integers, like this `const_cast<long int>((n/a+1) * (m/a+1))`.